# Django forms adding <div> after form field

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

Below is my form code :

```
class FMessage(forms.Form):
    From = forms.CharField()
    To = forms.CharField()
    Subject = forms.CharField()
    Message = forms.CharField()
```

and this is my html code:

```
<form method='POST' action='.'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

The code works fine by displaying forms and has not any issue in functionality, but now I need to wrap my form fields in html by a `div` like this:

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <input ... />
<div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to use custom Widget to this form field, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7692039/824132

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont render the form by using `form.as_p`. You need to show each field of the form, for example, by using `form.to`. By using this way, you can wrap the field 'to' into a div

```
 <div>{{ form.To}} </div>
```

For more detail, view this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)

Comment: Hmm div issue resolved but it creates an other problem, label is missing now :(its not taking label even after specifing .. `forms.CharField(label = 'Departure Place'`

Comment: Link from the answer above contains answer. You need to specify label manually like this: `{{ form.subject.label_tag }}`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Answer (score 18):

Seems like you do not really want to use the inbuilt `<p>` or `<table>` wrapped forms and rather want to display the fields wrapped within a `<div>'s`. You can simply iterate over fields in the form as follows.

```
{% if form %}
    <!-- Form Errors -->
    {% if form.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in form.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Display Form -->
    <form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="mydiv">
            <label class="mylabel">{{ field.label }}</label>
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Good answer. One note: you don't need the csrf_token tag inside the for loop; once per form is recommended. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/.

Comment: oops, my bad, of course it should be outside the for loop. Updated the answer.

Comment: error message is not display ...so what can i do for getting error message

Comment: thanks for ur replay i completed my task ...i add the line <li>field.errors</li>in inside mydiv