# Django templates: HTML validation errors

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm running my code through validator and it's coming back with four errors which I don't know how to fix as the code has been imported from django forms.

Does anyone know how to fix these?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">

    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus class="form-control" required id="id_username"> <span class="helptext">Required. 150 characters or
                fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span></p>
    <p><label for="id_first_name">First name:</label> <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required id="id_first_name"></p>
    <p><label for="id_last_name">Last name:</label> <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required id="id_last_name"></p>
    <p><label for="id_email">Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email" required id="id_email"></p>
    <p><label for="id_password1">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password1" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" required id="id_password1"> <span class="helptext">
                <ul>
                    <li>Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.</li>
                    <li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li>
                    <li>Your password can’t be a commonly used password.</li>
                    <li>Your password can’t be entirely numeric.</li>
                </ul>
            </span></p>
    <p><label for="id_password2">Password confirmation:</label> <input type="password" name="password2" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" required id="id_password2"> <span class="helptext">Enter the same password as before, for verification.</span></p>

    <div class="d-grid">
      <button class="btn btn-dark ">Register</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have used:

```
from django import forms
```

and in my views.py file I used:

```
from .forms import SignUpForm
```

my register.html page is as following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1 class="my-4">Register</h1>

<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <div class="d-grid">
            <button class="btn btn-dark ">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

[image: Error messages]

Comment: They are exactly as they say. You have a span around the ul - that is not valid HTML

Comment: Please add the form python code and the template you are using to display the form. Are you using and form library like `crispy-forms`?

Comment: `<ul>` is flow content, but `<p>` and `<span>` only permit phrasing content.  Move the `<ul>` outside of the `<p>` and re-style as needed.

Comment: Please update your question with the code instead of pasting into the comments. Thanks

Comment: Replace both `p` and `span` with `div` and no such errors are thrown. Read [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) comment above.

Comment: @ David and akaAbdullahMateen - I have imported the code from django forms so would I just fix it by putting the whole code with div tags on my register.html ?

Comment: @codingmartins Replace the `<span class="helptext" etc etc> ... </span>` with `<div class="helptext" ... etc etc> ... </div>` and import with `<div>{{ form.To }} </div>` rather than `{{ form.as_p }}`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15630799/18311567) to understand.